# How can I make this table?

Tags: tables, colorbox

Consider:

[image]

I want to duplicate this exact table. I'm stuck. How can I do it?

I've tried this code so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Color} & Numerical Value & Color & Numerical Value \\
\hline Black & \colorbox{black}{} & 0 & Green & \colorbox{green}{} \\
\hline Brown & \colorbox{brown}{} & 1 & Blue & \colorbox{blue}{}\\
\hline Red & \colorbox{red}{} & 2 & Violet & \colorbox{violet}{} \\
\hline Orange &  \colorbox{orange}{} & 3 & Gray & \colorbox{gray}{} \\
\hline Yellow & \colorbox{yellow}{} & 4 & White & \colorbox{white}{} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

With the code above, mine looks like this: I want to fix the right side of the table so that it looks like the left side.

[image]

How can I make the colored table the same width with the above table?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far!

Comment: @Mensch thank you! i've added the code right now :)

Comment: What is it that you think should be enhanced with your version?

Comment: @JasperHabicht i've just edited the post. i want to fix that part. can you please help,i'm struggling here. my time is short :(

Comment: Haha, I assume that everybody's time is short. Get yourself a coffee and then look at your code again: First you want six columns, but you only defined five. So change `|c|c|c|c|c|` to `|c|c|c||c|c|c|`, this will also add a double vertical border in the middle. Then you need to replace `Color` with `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Color}` (making the right part of your table header the same as the left). Then, what is eventually missing are just the digits in the last column.

Comment: Thank you SO much you just saved my life here!! One more question if you could help please! How can i make the colored tiny boxes just like that table? In my table you can't even see the white color because there is no black border around it,how could i possibly add that? @JasperHabicht

Comment: @AslıBilge See Mico's nice answer =)

Comment: @AslıBilge, please make it a habit to post code we‘d like to see here. Have a look here for some guidance: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790. Thank you

Comment: You can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ to generate code for tables, by merging/dividing cells. This graphical UI makes it easy to generate template for tables, along with other parameters of the tables.

Comment: @Damitr Please don't suggest these awful online table generators. The code they produce contains a lot of troublesome `\multicolumn{1}` which make it very hard to properly format the resulting tables.

Answer (score 9):

I'd avoid that dramatic spacing and also the too big squares.

I'd also avoid rules as much as possible, see the second realization.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\fcolorbox' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the second instance

\newcommand{\showcolor}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c||l|c|c|@{\vphantom{$\bigg|$}}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Color} & Numerical Value &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Color} & Numerical Value \\
\hline
Black  & \showcolor{black}  & 0 & Green  & \showcolor{green}  & 5 \\ \hline
Brown  & \showcolor{brown}  & 1 & Blue   & \showcolor{blue}   & 6 \\ \hline
Red    & \showcolor{red}    & 2 & Violet & \showcolor{violet} & 7 \\ \hline
Orange & \showcolor{orange} & 3 & Gray   & \showcolor{gray}   & 8 \\ \hline
Yellow & \showcolor{yellow} & 4 & White  & \showcolor{white}  & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcc @{\hspace{4em}} lcc @{}}
\toprule
Color && \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Numerical \\ Value \end{tabular} &
Color && \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Numerical \\ Value \end{tabular} \\
\midrule 
Black  & \showcolor{black}  & 0 & Green  & \showcolor{green}  & 5 \\
Brown  & \showcolor{brown}  & 1 & Blue   & \showcolor{blue}   & 6 \\
Red    & \showcolor{red}    & 2 & Violet & \showcolor{violet} & 7 \\
Orange & \showcolor{orange} & 3 & Gray   & \showcolor{gray}   & 8 \\
Yellow & \showcolor{yellow} & 4 & White  & \showcolor{white}  & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I guess you want `\fcolorbox`, not `\colorbox`, since the template has black framelines around the color boxes. And, if strict adherence to the template is a must, you should also modify the `tabular` environment so that it has 6 columns instead of 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\fcolorbox' macro
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\phantom{::}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{l|c|c|}}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Color} & Numerical Value & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Color} & Numerical Value \\ \hline 
Black  & \mybox{black}  & 0 & Green  & \mybox{green}  & 5 \\ \hline 
Brown  & \mybox{brown}  & 1 & Blue   & \mybox{blue}   & 6 \\ \hline 
Red    & \mybox{red}    & 2 & Violet & \mybox{violet} & 7 \\ \hline 
Orange & \mybox{orange} & 3 & Gray   & \mybox{gray}   & 8 \\ \hline 
Yellow & \mybox{yellow} & 4 & White  & \mybox{white}  & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: Speaking for myself, I don't think it's a good idea to increase the width of the table all the way to 40em. (Can't you make the other box a lot narrower?) But if you simply must set the table's width to 40em, I suggest you switch from a `tabular` to a `tabular*` environment, omit all vertical rules, and replace all `hline` directives with the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for '\fcolorbox' macro
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\phantom{::}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{tabular*}{40em}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lcc lcc }
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Color} & Numerical Value &
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Color} & Numerical Value \\ \midrule
Black  & \mybox{black}  & 0 & Green  & \mybox{green}  & 5 \\ \addlinespace
Brown  & \mybox{brown}  & 1 & Blue   & \mybox{blue}   & 6 \\ \addlinespace
Red    & \mybox{red}    & 2 & Violet & \mybox{violet} & 7 \\ \addlinespace
Orange & \mybox{orange} & 3 & Gray   & \mybox{gray}   & 8 \\ \addlinespace
Yellow & \mybox{yellow} & 4 & White  & \mybox{white}  & 9 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you SO much it worked!! I have one more question if you can answer please! i've edited the post if you could take a look . basically i want to make the table's width bigger

Comment: What's the width of the large rectangle that encases a multi-line formula? How do you generate it?

Comment: the width is 40em

Comment: @AslıBilge - Please see the addendum I posted. Speaking for myself, I don't think it's a good idea to make table so wide. Can't you make the rectangle that encases the multi-line formula narrower instead?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense,got it! Thank you so much for all the help,i really appreciate it. :))

Answer (score 3):

> how can i make the colored table the same width with the above table.

Probably applying the package `tabularx` would be the easiest way to achieve that. It lets you specify width of the whole table, while its `X`-column can be used to make the column(s) gets auto resized so the table achieve the desired width.

I also added two packages: `makecell` and `tikz`. `makecell` is useful in twofold: (1) cells accept `\\` in order to insert line breaks and (2) extra space is added around cells. The latter feature prevents a content from sticking to the table rules.

`tikz` package, on the other hand, allows drawing complex shapes in LaTeX. Here, it creates a box filled with a colour. I made a macro to avoid repetition and to help with more clarity in the code.

Below is a code for much more compact table than yours. I would suggest to keep a minimum number of rules as possible, just for clarity; perhaps the bar separating two groups would make sense, hence I have included it in the code below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}            % X-column and a thick bar
\usepackage{makecell}            % Multi lined cells with extra spaceing
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}    % Custom colour definitions
\usepackage{tikz}                % Colourful boxes

\newcommand\cbox[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.7ex]
        \node [minimum size=3mm, draw, fill=#1] {};}
\newcommand\xrule[1]{\noalign{\hrule height #1}}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[3pt]}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \renewcommand*\arraystretch{1.2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{ % <--- Specify width here
            Xcc
            !{\vrule width 1pt}
            Xcc
        }
        \xrule{1pt}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{Color}
        & \makecell{Num.\\Value}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Color}
        & \makecell{Num.\\Value} \\
        \xrule{0.6pt}
        Black  & \cbox{Black}  & 0 & Green  & \cbox{Green}  & 5 \\
        Brown  & \cbox{Brown}  & 1 & Blue   & \cbox{Blue}   & 6 \\
        Red    & \cbox{Red}    & 2 & Violet & \cbox{Violet} & 7 \\
        Orange & \cbox{Orange} & 3 & Gray   & \cbox{Gray}   & 8 \\
        Yellow & \cbox{Yellow} & 4 & White  & \cbox{white}  & 9 \\
        \xrule{1pt}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP has noted in a comment that the width should be 40em.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much @Celdor. I appreciate it!! :))

Comment: @Mico I didn't see that detail in OP's question. Nonetheless, it should be very simple for OP to alternate the code: `0.7\linewidth` should be changed to `40em`. However, in such a wide table, I no longer suggest abbreviations or even avoid line breaks to keep the table more balanced.